# JavaScript - Capture submit values from opened window

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, submit

My JavaScript app opens a third-party web-application on a new window (we submit a form with the action attribute pointing to this third-party url and the target attribute with "_blank". Unfortunately we must open this app in a new window because of IE compatibility mode.

At this third party application there is another form. I would like to know if there is a way to capture the submit values posted by this form so I can use them in my JavaScript app.

Thanks,

Gustavo

Comment: What languages use your application? Is a javascript native application or you use a server-side language?

Comment: It is a javascript native app.

Comment: checkout this question on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the technologies behind your app so i'll write for you some options

**1. Creating a cookie**

In Javascript you can work with cookies, so you can register multiple variables that lives globally in your application (But this is not optimal for this part of your application). you can find here some documentation: 
http://www.quirksmode.org/js/cookies.html

**2. Post Method**

[JavaScript post request like a form submit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133925/javascript-post-request-like-a-form-submit?rq=1)
I think this last option is the best to implement because suits perfectly for your case.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your help!

I managed to find a solution. In my page I created a form that submits using "_blank" as target. This opens a new browser window calling the third party app.

The form of this third party app is submitting to a webservice in my server. This webservice parses the form values and returns an html page with an embedded javascript code calling a function from the window.opener. In this function I included as parameters the values submitted from the third party app.

This is working fine in IE and Chrome.

Regards,

Gustavo